# Is it differentiable at $x=(0, 0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ \displaystyle f(x, y)=\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} $ be a multivariable function.
Examine if it is differentiable at $x=(0,0)$.

*I proved that the limit of the partial derivatives at $x=(0, 0)$ are $1, -1$ respectively. It is also easy to note that the partial derivatives there are not continuous. Hence to examine differentiability I have to check the limit:*

$$\lim_{\left ( x, y \right )\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{f(x, y)-f(0, 0)-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(0, 0)x-\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(0, 0)y}{\left \| x, y \right \|}$$

*I'm having some difficulty proving that this limit does not exist. P.S: I proved that the functin is continuous at $x=(0, 0)$ via sequences.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are examining the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}-x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
Switching to polar coordinates, $x=r \cos \theta,y=r \sin \theta$ we get the equivalent limit
$$\lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{r^3(\cos^3 \theta-\sin^3 \theta)}{r^2}-r(\cos \theta-\sin \theta)}{r}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: May be a dumb question... but isn't the ratio you provide independent of $r$?

Comment: @jameselmore That's exactly the point.

Answer (score 1):

To show $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, it is sufficient to show that the entire family of single-variable functions $g_p(x) \equiv f(x,px)$ for all $p\in \Bbb{R}$ have continuous derivatives at 
$x = 0$, and (because no value of $p$ gives a line along the $y$ axis) that $f(0,y)$ has a continous derivative at $(0,0)$.

$$g_p(x) = \frac{x^3(1-p^3)}{x^2(1+p^2)} = x\frac{1-p^3}{1+p^2}$$ 
$$
\frac{dg_p(x)}{dx} = \frac{1-p^3}{1+p^2}$$
which is obviously continous at $x=0$ and indeed everywhere else.

And $$f(0,y) = -y$$
$$
\frac{df(0,y)}{dy} = -1$$ which again is continuous at $y=0$.

So $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.